# QML: QChar Booleans are undefined

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

```
function myFunction(x)
{
    console.log(x.isLetter)
}

myFunction("s")
```

When I run this in a .qml file, it tells me that "isLetter" is undefined. Why?

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qchar.html#isLetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use Qt methods on JavaScript var, to do what you want prefer a pure js implementation:

```
x.match(/[a-z]/i);
```

Comment: http://regexone.com/  is an interactive tutorial, in case anyone needs to learn it.